# Importing flat XML data into SQLite database in c#.net

Tags: c#, xml, sqlite, ndbunit

I have generated an XML file by exporting my SQLite database in [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) [.net](/questions/tagged/.net).
My generated XML looks like this:

```xml
<root>
  <name1>
    <names>
      <id>5</id>           
      <from>Germany</from>
      <to>France</to>
      <through>
        <via>
          <id>7</id>
          <routeNo>5<routeNo>
          <route>Vienna<route>
        </via>
      </through>           
    </names>
    <names>
      <id>10</id>           
      <from>US</from>
      <to>Canada</to>
      <through>
        <via>
          <id>8</id>
          <routeNo>10<routeNo>
          <route>Mexico<route>
        </via>
      </through>           
    </names>
  </name1>
</root>
```

Then i transformed the above xml into an XML file like this

```xml
<names id="5" from="Germany" to="France"> 
  <through id="9" routeNo="5" route="Vienna" /> 
  <through id="10" routeNo="5" route="russia" /> 
</names>
```

I have imported this XML file into my SQLite database with the following code:

```cs
var sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection(
         "Data Source=SGLight_empty.fmeda;Version=3;New=True;Compress=True;");
NDbUnit.Core.INDbUnitTest sqliteDatabase 
              = new NDbUnit.Core.SqlLite.SqlLiteUnitTest(sqlite_conn);
   
sqliteDatabase.ReadXmlSchema("myXSD.xsd");
sqliteDatabase.ReadXml("myXML.xml");
sqliteDatabase.PerformDbOperation(NDbUnit.Core.DbOperationFlag.CleanInsertIdentity);
```

The import works for the normal XML file.

- The problem is i can't import the flat XML file transformed from the normal XML.
- Could anyone help me how to modify  it so that i can also import the data from flat XML?

Comment: Did you modify the xsd to match the flat XML?

Comment: i have created the XSD in server explorer by draging and droping the database tables. how to modify it for flat xml format ? modifying the XSD will work or there is any method for loading flat XML ?

Comment: @cahinton Could you please give me any example XSD which matches with flat XML ?

Answer (score 1):

An issue to consider is whether or not SQLite, even with a correct XSD for the flattened XML, will be able to recognized and match up the XML with the database schema that generated the full XML.  Why do you need to flatten the XML in the first place?

That being said, there is an xsd tool that comes with the Windows SDK that can infer an XSD from an arbitrary XML file.  I copied your "flat" xml into a file named temp.xml, ran `xsd temp.xml`, and received this XSD definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
  <xs:element name="names">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="through" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:attribute name="routeNo" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:attribute name="route" type="xs:string" />
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:attribute name="from" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:attribute name="to" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element ref="names" />
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: actually i can generate XSD from XML in visual studio. but. in my case, it was not working. then i needed to create XSD from sqlite database and it is working for normal XML data to be imported and i used NDbUnit for that. and, my project requires to export sqlite database to flat XML and import those data back to sqlite dataabase.

Comment: anyway, I am trying your approach.